# How to use React Router with Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, reactjs, react-router

I need to use `React Router` with a `Laravel` project.

But when I create a router on the `React Router` and try access, `Laravel` produces a "Route not exist" error.

How can I use `React Router` to manage Laravel project routes?

```
render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}/>
        <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/> // this route I trying access
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 47):

Create a route that maps everything to one controller, like so:

```php
Route::get('/{path?}', [
    'uses' => 'ReactController@show',
    'as' => 'react',
    'where' => ['path' => '.*']
]);
```

Then in your controller, just show the HTML page that contains the react root document:

```php
class ReactController extends Controller {
    public function show () {
        return view('react');
    }
}
```

Then do everything as normal with react router. Seems to work well for me.

---

**Update for Laravel 5.5**
If your controller only returns a view (like in the example above), you can replace all of the above code with this in your routes file:

```php
Route::view('/{path?}', 'path.to.view')
     ->where('path', '.*')
     ->name('react');
```

Comment: I thought it has something to do with https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/laravel-mix-solution-to-historyapifallback

Comment: For React-router v4 you can use the `/somePath/{path?}` and then in your React:
`<BrowserRouter basename="somePath">`
This will enable you to have dynamically routed paths in react, but also directly link-able sub-paths.

Comment: how I can able to detect a path that doesn't exists ?

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid the `{path?}` part means it will match any URL. If you put that at the bottom of your routes file, anything that isn't matched to a previously defined URL will be matched at this one.

Comment: @JakeTaylor With this approach if you hit `/bar/url`, it would first be handle by Laravel, then React-router and show its respective component?

Comment: @FernandoMontoya exactly. It will go through the route named 'react', which will show the specified view - where React would be loaded and you can use React Router as normal.

Comment: @JakeTaylor How do you deal with `webpack-dev-server`, it tries to get its updates from `http://localhost/foo.hot.json`, which Laravel will respond with the `path.to.view`, thus completely broke Hot Reload.

Comment: @FernandoMontoya I'm not sure, but that's out of scope for this question. I would open a new question if I were you.

Comment: Adding up path as '.*' make the assets links and other static link point to react. better add `->where('path', '^((?!api|assets).)*$')` in order to ignore those links.

Comment: @KaranSharma in my case (most cases AFAIK), your nginx/apache config checks for file existence before passing onto the application, so that shouldn't be necessary, but YMMV!

Answer (score 20):

Based on Jake Taylor answer (which is correct, by the way) : it has a little mistake, is missing a quotation mark after `'/{path?}'` , just the last one.

Also, if you don't need to use a Controller and just redirect back to your view, you can use it like this:

```php
Route::get( '/{path?}', function(){
    return view( 'view' );
} )->where('path', '.*');
```

**Note:**
Just make sure to add this Route at the end of all of your routes in the routes file ( web.php for Laravel 5.4 ), so every existing valid route you have may be catched before reaching this last one.

Comment: Thanks! This works but I get a console error: 
`DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://laravelreact.test/js/bootstrap.js.map`

Comment: Recommended [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44375689/10525009) if you are using Laravel API

Answer (score 18):

This seems works for me

### For any react routes

```
Route::get('{reactRoutes}', function () {
    return view('welcome'); // your start view
})->where('reactRoutes', '^((?!api).)*$'); // except 'api' word
```

### For laravel routes

```
Route::get('api/whatever/1', function() {
    return [
        'one' => 'two',
        'first' => 'second'
    ];
});

Route::get('api/something/2', function() {
    return [
        'hello' => 'good bye',
        'dog' => 'cat'
    ];
});
```

Comment: Works well, nice.

Comment: thanks man u saved me ! I thought why my api tests are not working

Comment: In order to get the above to work in api.php I had to remove api/ from the route::get. Laravel already includes it in api.php but not in web.php.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT in Feb 2022**: I posted this solution when the latest Laravel was V5 and react-router was V4. There could be a better solution now, because both Laravel and react-router evolved a lot since then

==================================================

How about using `<HashRouter>`?

E.g.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    HashRouter,
    Route,
    Link
}from 'react-router-dom';
import Profile from './Profile';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <Link to="/profile" replace>Profile</Link>
                <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
            </HashRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

In Laravel's router...

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('index'); //This view is supposed to have the react app above
});
```

With `HashRouter`, your client side routing is done with `#` (Fragment Identifier), which is not read by Laravel's routing (i.e. server side routing)

Upon arriving this page, the URL is `/`.

Clicking the link will make the URL `/#/profile` and the component will appear.

After that, if you refresh the page, you wont' see the `Route not exist` error. This is because, from Laravel's perspective, the URL is still `/`. (The component `Profile` still remains there.)

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter

Hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: But it's ugly as sin :(

Comment: @imperium2335 but it is much better than hitting the backend to return the same static view over and over again like all the other answers here.

Comment: @Julian The server side isn't called on every page change from react-router. A fresh load will hit the server which will return the static view, then any routing/url changes from there on is entirely client side.

Comment: Ugly indeed. However, I haven't been able to make it work by any other mean. Working will Laravel 8. Thanks.

Comment: Recommended [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44375689/10525009) if you are using Laravel API

Answer (score 3):

You can return your index page and browserHistory of React will handle anything else.

```
Route::pattern('path', '[a-zA-Z0-9-/]+');
Route::any( '{path}', function( $page ){   
     return view('index');
});
```