# Laravel React-router 404 for Resource files (CSS/JS)

Tags: laravel, reactjs, react-router

I'm working with Laravel (5.6) and React (16.4.1+react-router) on a project, and got into a problem maybe some of you having similar problem, so I wonder we could get some ideas. Recently I have found a solution for refreshing error (404) here: [How to use React Router with Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719951/how-to-use-react-router-with-laravel#44375689) and one of the soulutions solved /app/{anything} problem, too.

Now my problem is with resource files (`/css`, `/js`) from `/public` folder. I tried to do a workaround with the same regex as /app =>

`Route::get( '/{path?}', function() {
    return view( 'home' );
})->where('path', '^((?!app|api|css|js).)*$');`

but it's still not working as expected. As I read, we must put this snippet after all routes we included in our app, because of Laravel's caching mechanism, but it's not working with neither /css, neither /js resource files in `/public` folder > but works with `/api` and `/app` routes, and anything I add before /{path?}.

Is there any solutions for this? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help,
LeFizzy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution for this, and I thought I must share this with others looking for this. First, it was by a mistake. In the `home.blade.php` view I linked my resource files incorrectly, like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mydomain.something/css/styles.css" />` and that's why it didn't find the route, and matched with /{path?/ - so it's actually rendered the home view rather than returning the resource file.

For this, Laravel offers a solution for this by looking for your assets in `/public` folder, just by linking your files simple like: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/styles.css')}}" />` and almost same solution for JS (local) assets: `<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" ></script>`.

To mention, you should link external (from other networks) like I did with my Laravel app which didn't worked due to the problem I asked for.

Good luck with it. :)