# React Router in Laravel Blade 404 Not Found Error for deeper url Levels

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am incorporating React in an **existing** Laravel app.

- I created a separate view (documents.blade.php), inside which my root React component is rendered.
- In my web.php I created a route that points to this documents view.
- Inside my React component I am using React Router.

Although the url for document.blade is working, and my react component is rendering inside it, when I am trying to create sub links with React Router
I am getting a 404 Error, Not Found.

Any ideas on why React Rooter doesn't work?

In my web.php I have tried all the ways bellow:

```
Route::get('{locale}/documents', function() {
        return view('documents');
    });

Route::get('{locale}/documents', function() {
        return view('documents');
    })->where('{locale}/documents', '.*');

Route::view('{locale}/{path?}', 'documents');
```

In my app.js I have tried:

```
return (

    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
        <Route path="/create" component={AddDocument} />
        <Route path="/edit" component={EditDocument} />
        <Route path="/details" component={DocumentDetails} />
    </Switch>
);
```

or

```
return (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
        <Route path={props.locale + "document/create"} component={AddDocument} />
        <Route path={props.locale + "document/edit/:id"} component={EditDocument} />
        <Route path={props.locale + "document/details/:id"} component={DocumentDetails} />
    </Switch>
);
```

I am accessing the top level url: 
http://localhost:8090/public/en/documents (Renders my app component)
,but anything below that is not working like this one:
http://localhost:8090/public/en/documents/create (Does not display my Create component or anything else. I get the 404 error )

Has anyone worked on anything similar?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719951/how-to-use-react-router-with-laravel) can help you :)

Comment: Thank you, I have already read this and pretty much everything relative here. :)
I found the error, it was in the path I was using in the <Route> components!