# When first localhost is loaded, it's not showing the component with the code I have

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

When I first launch *npm run watch* it's directing me to *localhost:3000" which I want to show the homepage or BookList right away. But I am getting *404 Not Found*. I don't want to go to *localhost:3000/home* manually. I want to see the *BookList* right away when first launched the server.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./Header";
import BookList from "./BookList";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";


class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Header />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/home" component={BookList} />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={BookList} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Yaraku Book Store</title>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the whole file ? Including all imports. This code fragment worked fine when executed.

Comment: I edited so you can see it wider.

Comment: Did you update routes/web.php as well ? This question might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719951/how-to-use-react-router-with-laravel

Comment: @user54321 just like this Route::view('/{path}', 'app');