# React-router v5.2 routes aren't working, only home page is displayed

Tags: reactjs

I am using router version 5.2 and I am trying to make routes in file `app.js`.
My routes look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'; // if you use just render()
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            {/* Using the `component` prop */}
            <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
            <Route path="/display-item" component={DisplayProduct} />
            <Route path="/category/:id" component={DisplayCategory} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" component={OneProduct} />
            <Route path="/checkout" component={CheckOut} />
            <Route path="/orderPlaced" component={OrderPlaced} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>,
      document.getElementById('crud-app'),
    );
```

Problem is that only route `/` is working. So only home page is displayed.

When I try to go to `http://localhost:8000/#/display-item` nothing happens. So I am still on homepage and I don't have any warnings or errors in console.

If I go to `http://localhost:8000/display-item` then I get error `GET http://localhost:8000/display-item 404 (Not Found)`

Please anyone had similar problem? How to solve this?

Thank you!

UPDATE:
[image: page not found]

[image: home page]

Comment: How did you import `Router`?

Comment: Like this `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: Everything looks correct. http://localhost:8000/display-item should take you to `DisplayProduct` component and You do not get a **404 Error** with react router.

Comment: Before version 5.2 I have used version 3.2.6 and hashHistory and everything worked good. Now when I upgraded to version 5.2 and changed route like that it is not workin. I have attached image in question so you can see

Comment: Are you using Laravel? Looks like a route issue on the backend.

Comment: Yes, I am using laravel, any idea what might be, because on react router version 3.2.6 everything is working

Comment: It kind of depends on your setup in terms of routing. How about using `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRoute`? This is handy to look at if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719951/how-to-use-react-router-with-laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with backend Laravel, beside routes in react, you should define routes in `web.php` file

```
Route::view('/', 'welcome');
Route::view('/display-item', 'welcome');
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the home route as the last statement in switch then it will work. in your code every path matches with '/' so every time it will go to the home route.If you place it at the last then it will search for exact path.

Comment: exact keyword is used for this right?