# Unable to connect with a dynamic route directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm having trouble with react-router's dynamic routes.

Here's how my dynamic route is set up:

```
<Route path="users/:id" element={<SomeComponent />} />
```

Whenever I redirect to this route through a link like this:

```
<Link to={`../users/${some_id}`}>
```

or through navigate() like this:

```
navigate(`../users/${some_id}`)
```

I'm able to load the page just fine. But when I refresh that page, or when I type in the same url manually, I get a 404 error.

I'm wondering why that is.

For the backend, I'm using laravel, and I've set up a catch-all route like this:

```
Route::view('/{path?}', 'app');
```

Comment: I think you are omitting the inital slash on the path definition. Have you tried using path like this `<Route path="/users/:id" element={<SomeComponent />} />`? And then redirecting using `<Link to={`/users/${some_id}`}>` ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Still no success. To clarify: aside from dynamic routes, I also have static ones, which are set up in the same fashion. They work. So, I'm having this issue only with dynamic routes.

Comment: i don't know laravel very well but digging in the web i found this `Route::get( '/{path?}', function(){
    return view( 'view' );
} )->where('path', '.*');` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719951/how-to-use-react-router-with-laravel). Maybe it can be helpfull